# Can I Update List Item Using My Particular Field Value Insted of ID Using Rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, updatelistitems

**I am trying to update share point list item using rest api.**

I can update Item using ID but I want to Update that item which column Name **Title** is like **"DA5000"** its unique field so can I do this ?? if yes then how to achieve this..?

I was try to update using ID its work well but I want to Update using title item value

Any Help will Appreciated

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you add some Background as to why you want this? Might give more and possibly better solutions

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends how you are getting the item.

If you are getting it via the URL like this:

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('News')/items(50)
```

Where the number in the brackets "(50)" is the item ID you can get an item e.G. like this:

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('News')/items?$filter=Title eq 'FAQ'
```

So the URL is looking for an item, where in the title column FAQ is the content.

**In general:**

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('<ListName>')/items?$filter=<InternalColumnName> eq '<Value>'
```

To check the internal column names you can just use this:

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('<ListName>')/items
```

Then use that name for the  in the filter.

Hope this could help.

Comment: I was tried it  but its give 400 bad request error

Comment: updated answer. Could you add the output of that (the column you want to filter) in your question?

Comment: patrick i want to filter title column. have you try to update like this before? is it work?

Comment: actually in my when i approve in my one list then one random unique string generate and add in this list.so i don’t have that item ID .but i have that string so i want to update on that.

Comment: Didn't tried it, but if you get the item via /_api/lists/getbytitle('News')/items?$filter=Title eq 'DA5000' you also get the ID of the item. Check the xml output. So I guess there should not be a problem.

Comment: i knew i get it id using this but for that i have to make two request. so i was trying for  using title .

Comment: As I mentioned, I didn't tried it. I am sorry, that's all I can help you by now.

Comment: As Patrick mentions in his answer, you need to do two REST calls. First to get the ID of the item, then to update.